# IIS default.aspx not working

Tags: asp.net, iis, localhost

I have my iis set up and I can view html pages but I cannot view the default aspx. I can view the test aspx. Any reason why I may not be able to view it?

Comment: What is the url are you putting in?

Comment: What do you mean by “cannot view”? Is it lurking from you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default.aspx file in your mvc app isnt really for viewing. What url is it your trying to view?